# Import 3rd Party Page Views Data on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Is there a way to import 3rd party page view data to Google Analytics?

For example, if I have file download information from my server logs, could I put the information on Google Analytics and have it show up in the standard reports or a custom report alongside the existing pageview data already provided by Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to do it within 4 hours of the hit being logged. Take a look at the [GA measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/). The hour limit is due to the [qt param](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) (milliseconds from hit to api upload).

Comment: So it looks like in measurement protocol, it's sending hits one at a time. Is there a way to batch the hit data.  For example if my server logs say a PDF was downloaded 50 times, would I have to send 50 POST requests to Google Analytics servers? This seems the closest to what I'd need, but the reason I ask is because it seems like there's a hard limit of 10 million hits/month/property.

Comment: Sadly, no batch process available :(

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is Data Import:

> Data Import lets you upload data from external sources and combine it
>   with data you collect via Google Analytics. You can then use Google
>   Analytics to organize and analyze all of your data in ways that better
>   reflect your business.

Detailed information: [About Data Import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en).

Comment: But one cannot import pageviews (only add info to existing interactions) with data import, which seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: The documentation states: `Depending on the type of data you've imported, you can use either a standard report or create a Custom Report to display the imported data`. Alternative techniques would imply custom variables or dimensions, events, or using the API to build a custom dashboard.

Comment: From the examples and from playing around it seems like Data Import is for augmenting existing GA data, so adding more columns instead of adding more rows. It seems to require a key to join your augmented data too and in most cases that looks like a pageURL. I don't know if there's a good way to add a new pageURL at all and then subsequently alter the pageview data for it through Data Import.