# Import 3rd Party Data on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a project which was using [statcounter](https://statcounter.com/) to track visitors and now I need to implement Google Analytics and migrate the existing data to it. It's that possible?

As far as i could search, [Data Import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en) does not applies here, because I need to add new data information and  not add more info to my current data.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706786/import-3rd-party-page-views-data-on-google-analytics) similar question, but, if I understood right, I can't import old data? I have years of data from statcounter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import 3rd Party Page Views Data on Google Analytics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706786/import-3rd-party-page-views-data-on-google-analytics)

Comment: This really is a duplicate to the question you linked.There is nothing to add to the linked answer. Currently, and for the foreseeable future, on cannot create hits via data import and cannot set dates for hit send via the measurement protocol.

Comment: I know its the same question, as I said above, but the solution given there could be outdated and, even if it isn't, clearly does not fit what I'm asking here. I'm still searching for a solution, if I find anything I will update here.

Comment: It's not so much that I really care personally, but if you are both intent on ignoring this sites rules and dismissing answers you do not like then what is the point in asking ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff Obviously I'm not making myself clear here, sorry. It's not about whether I like or not the answer. Is about my current scenario. The answer, given to the question I linked above, fits the OP needs. About this site rules: it's not a duplicate if you are asking for non duplicate answers, like I did. I recommend you read more about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844) and/or [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).